# Best way to search for human names with elasticsearch rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have the following setup in my Rails 4 application via the [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) gem.  If I search for a technical term such as "appellate" in the description field (which may be repeated more than once), I get back search results.  But if I search for a name, whether first, last, or first and last, I seem to get nothing. Am I supposed to do something for string type fields?  (keeping in mind that description is a text field in Rails and first and last names are string fields in Rails)  Keep in mind that a first name such as "John" only appears in the first name field (last name is analogous to this), so I wonder if that is part of the issue?

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base


  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  index_name [Rails.env, model_name.collection.gsub(/\//, '-')].join('_')



  settings index: { number_of_shards: 2 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do

      indexes :first_name, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets', copy_to: 'full_name'
      indexes :last_name, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets', copy_to: 'full_name'
      indexes :email, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'

      indexes :description, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :full_name, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
    end
  end

  def self.search_trials(search_terms)
     response = ClinicalTrial.search(
      size: 20, 
       query: {
          multi_match: { 
              "query" => search_terms,
              "type" => "cross_fields",
              "fields" => "_all"
           }
      }
     )
     response.records
   end

 end
```

Comment: I can understand "analyzer" option but not "index_options". Haven't tested that in Ruby but in plain ES, "index_options" doesn't have a "english" value available.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo on my part late at night - when I changed it, I still had the same options.